# Why does LINQPad.exe need to be called LINQPad.exe to run?

Tags: .net, process, linqpad

I use LINQPad to connect to different environments, say "local", and "development". The connection settings are in LINQPad.exe's config file.

To help me organize my settings, I thought I'd make a couple of copies of LINQPad.exe, renaming them with corresponding config files, like this:

- LINQPad.local.exe
- LINQPad.local.config
- LINQPad.development.exe
- LINQPad.development.config

But LINQPad.exe complains at start up:

The application must be named LINKPad.exe in order to run.

Why is this?

PS Clearly I'm not asking how to manage my config files (I have different folders now) - I was more curious as to what programming reason there could be to enforce the name of a process?

Comment: LINQPad was written by [Joseph Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/). He *might* have enforced this so you that you couldn't rename it and redistribute it as your own. As for the specific reason why, [ask him](http://www.albahari.com/contact.aspx). He might answer.

Comment: Just put copies in separate folders, allowing you to keep the original name...

Comment: OK, I give up. What's with the close votes? It's a reasonable question - with a reasonable answer. How is it not constructive??? Should I advise LINQPad users NOT to use StackOverflow?

Comment: OK - so apparently now LINQPad is not related to programming. I've directed users of LINQPad not to ask questions related to LINQPad on StackOverflow: https://www.linqpad.net/feedback.aspx.

Comment: Use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", @"C:\Shared\app.config"); before accessing any config values. You could as well get current script path using Util class and derive filename of config from script filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source in Reflector, you'll see that it requires a specific name.

```
if (Path.GetFileName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).ToLowerInvariant() != "linqpad.exe")
{
    MessageBox.Show("The application must be named LINQPad.exe in order to run.", "LINQPad");
}
```

It also references config files by name, so it may enforce the assembly name just to keep things simple.

Answer (score 5):

The reason this is enforced is that your queries have a dependency on LINQPad.exe (for methods such as .Dump()). Hence if you rename the file, the CLR won't be able to find the correct assembly.

Comment: Is it that hard to reference a renamed exe? Just like you limit it, you can just determine the reference.

Comment: The CLR doesn't like it when you rename assembly references that are strongly named - try in in Visual Studio.

Comment: I was not aware of this. But this does not seem related to strong naming. From a small test, adding a symlink to the original module name to the renamed assembly makes it work (but hardly a solution ;p). I assume the same will happen with normal assemblies.

Comment: @Joe, interesting, thanks.